# How to make snack bar and fab to move together

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I want to move snack bar and fab to move together like happen in default  behaviour but by default it happens only when we click on fab, the fab makes place for `snackbar` and fab itself moves up,

But want it to happen when some other event happen like other button liked on layout not fab itself, how can i trigger fab to move up and make place for `snackbar` when other button on layout clicks

Thanks

Onclick of button:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
             if(spinner.getText().length() <= 0){
                 showListMenu(spinner);
             }else{
                 showSnack("Added to bag we will hold it for 1 hour!", view.getRootView());
             }
        }
```

Inside showSnack:

```
 Snackbar.make(view.getRootView(), getResources().getString(R.string.fab_msg), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

    final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.bounce);
    double animationDuration = 2 * 1000;
    myAnim.setDuration((long)animationDuration);

    MyBounceInterpolator interpolator = new MyBounceInterpolator(0.20, 20.00);

    myAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    fab.startAnimation(myAnim);
```

Comment: Post your Java code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just anchor fab with snackbar like this:

```
Snackbar.make(view.findViewById(R.id.fab), getResources().getString(R.string.fab_msg), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
```

Comment: blackHawk 's answer worked. Just remove one view after .make(view)

Answer (score 2):

Use `CoordinatorLayout` that's enough, no need to change anything on Java code. Add your button inside your `CoordinatorLayout`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For both click event `SnackBar` and `Fab` moves up smoothly

```
  fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```